# Difference between getter and accessing it directly

Tags: flutter

For example I have a field that I want to access in my app view. I have this provider

```dart
class User with ChangeNotifier{
   String userNick = "test";

   String get getName() => userNick;
}
```

What will be the difference, if I access the nick this way in my app vs getter?

```dart
context.watch<User>().userNick;
```

vs

```dart
context.watch<User>().getName();
```

If I don't use the getter and my userNick changes, will I not see it refreshing in my app or?

Comment: Look for encapsulation

Comment: Getters don't always just get.  Classes can return calculated values as well.

Comment: Think this (`String get getName()`) is invalid syntax - getters must not have arguments? In answer to your question, usually the provider pattern uses private fields + getters and setters. The idea is a variable `_a` can be 'gotten' using `get a => _a`, and set using `set a(T newA){}`. Inside the setter `notifyListeners()` is usually called after changing the variable (`_a = newA`), which 'refreshes' your app.

Comment: In most programming languages, you should prefer getters and setters to avoid making breaking API changes in case someday you need them to do additional work.  However, [there is no need to wrap fields in getters/setters in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61720221/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getters/setters are preferred for use the data properly. If you use the data directly, you can update it when you even don't wanna update it and this type of logical mistakes takes too much time to detect and fix. Also, it is safe way to manipulate the data.

---

Encapsulation is an object-oriented programming concept that binds together the data and functions that manipulate the data, and that keeps both safe from outside interference and misuse. Data encapsulation led to the important OOP concept of data hiding.

from: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming

---

For more, you can search for encapsulation online.