# set/get keywords in Flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new at dart language and as a person who knows Java i did not understand get/set keywords in dart.What does get/set keywords does can you explain.

Comment: The point is to make getter/setter functions look the same as accessing member variables.  [That's useful for future-proofing without cluttering the class's public interface](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61721254/).

Answer (score 0):

This is a function that makes using `getter` and `setter` more convenient.

```
String _name = "test";
```

***get***

```
//the same expression
String get name => _name;

String getName(){
  return _name;
}
```

***set***

```
//the same expression
set name(String name) => _name = name;

void setName(String name){
   _name = name;
}
```