# Why i have to implement setter in a class implements abstract class in dart after i make the fields final and make a constructor?

Tags: dart, abstract-class

I made this abstract class

```
abstract class API {
  //* ---- abstract fields , Methods ---- *//
  int? timeOut;
  int? getTimeOut();
}
```

then i implemented it with a class and made the field final

```
class GetData implements API {
   @override
  final int? timeOut; 


  GetData(int? ta) : timeOut = ta;

  @override
  int? getTimeOut() {
    return timeOut;
  }

   @override
  set timeOut(int? _timeOut) {
    timeOut = _timeOut;
  } 
}
```

so my question why i got error if i don't implement the setter even if the class has a constructor ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Dart, a non-`final` field is implicitly equivalent to providing a getter and a setter with that field's name.  A `final` field is implicitly equivalent to providing a getter with no setter.

Therefore your base class provides an interface with getters *and* setters.  But when you try to override it with a `final` field in the derived class, you're no longer providing an implicit setter, now your derived class would no longer implement the base class's required interface (and therefore the derived class would no longer [*substitutable*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) where the base class is expected).  That is not allowed, so you get a compile-time error.

If you don't want the derived class to provide a setter, don't make a setter part of the base class interface:

```dart
abstract class API {
  int? get timeOut;
}

class GetData implements API {
  @override
  final int? timeOut; 

  GetData(int? ta) : timeOut = ta;
}
```

And note that the `getTimeOut` method is redundant; you already have a `timeOut` getter (and also see [Why should I avoid wrapping fields in getters and setters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61720221/)).

Comment: But Do you agree with me that is kind of bugs ?

Comment: @MahmoudHabib No.  Why do you think it's a bug?  It's an error to make a derived class that does not conform to the base class interface.

Comment: try to create an instance from the GetData class and try to set timeout value ( after constructor) , you'll get an error , so this kind of behavior  is not right

Comment: @MahmoudHabib The behavior of requiring that the derived class provide a setter is correct.  Your attempt at providing such a setter is *not*.  Your setter calls itself recursively in an infinite loop.  The bug is in your API design and implementation, not in Dart.

Comment: @MahmoudHabib I've edited my question to show how to fix your classes.

Comment: It's not clear what you think the error should or shouldn't be. This is how Dart works, the `int? timeout` declaration in `API` defines an interface with the interface members `int? get timeout` and `void set timeout(int?)`. Your subclass must implement these. If you don't *want* those members in the interface, you should change the declaration to, e.g., `abstract final int? timeOut;` or `int? get timeOut;`, neither of which introduce a setter in the interface.
That your subclass can't *use* the setter for anything is a sign that it shouldn't be there, and therefore shouldn't be in `API`.